# Array with bubble sort and odd/even list - Anyone knows how to remove duplicate element in my even list?

Tags: java, arrays, list, for-loop

Regardless of the programming language you use. You will undoubtedly encounter data while dealing with arrays, particularly duplicates, that you will want to get rid of.

This is my [Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cg2QT.png)

I already inputted the correct syntax of even list array is there something that I missed?

Anyone knows how to remove duplicate element in my even list?

***Here's my code:***

```
import java.util.*;
import java.util.Iterator;
public class ArrayBubbleSortwithOddandEven {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        int size, temp;
        System.out.print("Size of the list: ");
        size = scanner.nextInt();
        int number[] = new int[size];
        int oddarray[] = new int[size];
        int evenarray[] = new int[size];
        int odd = 0;
        int even = evenarray.length - 1;

        for (int i = 0; i < number.length; i++) {
            System.out.print("Input: ");
            number[i] = scanner.nextInt();
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            for (int swap = 1; swap < (size - i); swap++) {
                if (number[swap - 1] > number[swap]) {
                    temp = number[swap - 1];
                    number[swap - 1] = number[swap];
                    number[swap] = temp;
                }
            }
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < number.length; i++) {
            if (number[i] % 2 != 0) {
                oddarray[odd++] = number[i];
            } else {
                evenarray[even--] = number[i];
            }
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < number.length; i++) {
            evenarray[even] = evenarray[i];
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < number.length; i++) {
            oddarray[odd] = oddarray[i];
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) { //Bubble sort
            for (int swap = 1; swap < (size - i); swap++) {
                if (evenarray[swap - 1] > evenarray[swap]) {
                    temp = evenarray[swap - 1];
                    evenarray[swap - 1] = evenarray[swap];
                    evenarray[swap] = temp;
                }
            }
        }

        System.out.println("Odd List:"); //Print Odd list
        for (odd = 0; odd < oddarray.length; odd++) {
            System.out.println("List " + odd + ": " + (oddarray[odd]));
        }
        System.out.println("Even List:"); //Print Even list
        for (even = 0; even < evenarray.length; even++) {
            System.out.println("List " + even + ": " + (evenarray[even]));
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use a Set\HashMap to remember which number you already discover during your iteration. GOOD LUCK !

You can read about Data Structures - just google it :).

here a few questions that might help you understand.

[Data Structures for hashMap, List and Set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2723781/data-structures-for-hashmap-list-and-set)

[Why key in HashMap can't be duplicated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32866652/why-key-in-hashmap-cant-be-duplicated)

[how to find duplicate item position from set in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38823210/how-to-find-duplicate-item-position-from-set-in-java)